# How to convert array column to int array in Pandas?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame `grouped_reps` that contains names and a certain array of numbers associated with those names.

The dataframe is basically like:

```
grouped_reps = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['John', 'Mary', 'Tom'],
    'util_rate': [[1.0, 0.75, 0.90], [1.0, 0.80, 0.87],
                  [0.74, 0.34, 0.90, 0.45]]
})
```

Both the columns are currently object data types.

I'm trying to take the mean of each array associated with a name and store it in a new column in the dataframe, but to do this I have to convert the array to an float array first. I'm trying to do this by:

```
grouped_reps["util_rate"] = grouped_reps["util_rate"].astype(str).astype(float)
```

But I get this Error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[1.0, 0.75, 0.9]'
```

Comment: @HenryEcker I don't know how to make the problem reproducible as this problem is unique to me b/c of having an imported dataset.

Comment: @garchukins Your edits moved in the right direction! Take a look at the edit's I've made for some ideas. Generally you want to make sure that your attempt works on the sample frame as well, for example if the dataframe is `grouped_reps` don't call it `df`, if the column is 'util_rate' don't call it 'B'. Additionally, report the error message for the _sample_ data so it is reproducible.

Comment: @HenryEcker Thank you very much for your help! You helped me understand what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the mean of each list, [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html#pandas-series-explode) the list into multiple rows, convert to `float` via [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html#pandas-series-astype) then calculate the [`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mean.html#pandas-series-mean) on level=0:

```
grouped_reps['mean'] = (
    grouped_reps['util_rate'].explode().astype(float).mean(level=0)
)
```

`grouped_reps`:

```
      A                util_rate      mean
0  John         [1.0, 0.75, 0.9]  0.883333
1  Mary         [1.0, 0.8, 0.87]  0.890000
2   Tom  [0.74, 0.34, 0.9, 0.45]  0.607500
```

---

Explanation:

Explode produces a series where each element is in its own row:

```
grouped_reps['util_rate'].explode()
```

```
0     1.0
0    0.75
0     0.9
1     1.0
1     0.8
1    0.87
2    0.74
2    0.34
2     0.9
2    0.45
Name: util_rate, dtype: object
```

Convert to float:

```
grouped_reps['util_rate'].explode().astype(float)
```

```
0    1.00
0    0.75
0    0.90
1    1.00
1    0.80
1    0.87
2    0.74
2    0.34
2    0.90
2    0.45
Name: util_rate, dtype: float64
```

Since the index aligns with the index from each row, we can take the mean relative to `level=0`:

```
grouped_reps['util_rate'].explode().astype(float).mean(level=0)
```

```
0    0.883333
1    0.890000
2    0.607500
Name: util_rate, dtype: float64
```